# Android : Freeze when taking picture

Tags: android, asynchronous, camera, freeze

I have a 2 seconds freeze when taking a picture (without preview), distributed like this :

```
Camera cameraBack = Camera.open(CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK); // 0.400 sec
...
cameraBack.startPreview(); // 0.800 sec
...
cameraBack.takePicture(null, null, null, new Camera.PictureCallback() {public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {...}}); // 0.900 sec
```

So I tried to run it inside an async thread :

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ...
    }).start();
```

But this didn't change anything. Indeed, I saw later in the documentation, that these functions were already executed on an independant thread.

The problem is : This freeze ruins my user experience, and worse, sometimes the picture is not taken due to the CPU overhead :

```
Suspending all threads took: 7.659ms
```

How could I resolve that?